# BIOS doesn't detect windows drive but the drive is accessible on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

The setup:

1x256gb M.2 drive (Ubuntu boot drive)

1x1Tb SSD (Ubuntu extra storage)

1x1Tb SSD (Windows 11 boot drive)

1x2Tb HDD (General storage)

For a while I was running PopOS on the M.2 and decided I wanted to change to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu from a USB and let the installer wipe/format the M.2 drive that was running PopOS.

After this my BIOS doesn't detect any drive other than the M.2. I can boot into Ubuntu fine. I cannot however, boot into windows.

From checking the file system in Ubuntu I can see the windows drive, I can copy files from it (currently doing it now in-case of data loss). It's visible in the likes of gparted.

I have fast boot etc disabled. Tried booting using CSM, while it recognised the other drives when I rebooted and went back into the BIOS, it fails to boot the windows drive and instead displayed a message saying to select a different boot device.

Any help much appreciated. Any more information needed just ask and I'll do my best to provide it.

Comment: It sounds like you've deleted your EFI partition. You might want to try to boot a windows installation medium and run startup repair

Comment: This. Your motherboard firmware (UEFI, not BIOS unless you have a decade old computer) will boot either a boot menu (if present) or the default bootx64.efi file. That was likely located on the M2.  Motherboard boots that, from there you select a bootloader to continue with, basically choosing OS. Reformatting the M2 wiped that and only the default loader for Ubuntu got installed.

Comment: Thanks both for the comments. I've definitely learned something, yes it's a UEFI board (I never knew the difference between UEFI and BIOS). I had a feeling that somehow I had done something to the effect of wiping the bootable part of the windows drive / information used by the bootloader. I attempted to perform a windows install repair, but it couldn't find any issues when running.

Comment: I've managed to get it working again, just had to do old reliable and re-install windows. I had managed to move my important stuff (honestly, modded skyrim and saves) to one of the linux drives and then accessed that drive from windows when I had it re-installed. It's all working now.